# Setting value = Null does not return true when testing if value = Null -- perplexing

Tags: t-sql, null

When setting a Variable to Null but I need to check and verify it is null or another value.  It does not work if I compare the two, per this test if @tmp = null returns False even though I set @tmp = null.  However @tmp is null returns True.  Per this how do I compare another value to @tmp which is also null to see if they match?  Since these are Integer I can not set to an empty string nor would zero be appropriate to remove Nulls.

```
declare @tmp integer = null

select case when @tmp = null then 1 when @tmp is null then 2 else 3 end 

-- Result is 2
```

Expected result is 1, but 2 is returned.

Comment: You may want to review [How to Get NULLs Horribly Wrong in SQL Server](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/how-to-get-nulls-horribly-wrong-in-sql-server/).

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are assuming that `@tmp = null` is a valid way of comparing the value of `@tmp` and `NULL`.

In fact, you should be using `IS NULL` to test for a `NULL` value:

```
declare @tmp integer = null

select case when @tmp IS NULL then 1 when @tmp is null then 2 else 3 end
```

Think of it as is *this undefined thing* the same as *that undefined thing*: No it is not.

However, is *this undefined thing* actually *undefined*: Yes it is.

Incidentally, this is due to the fact that by default, SQL Server uses the standard ANSI NULL approach to `NULL`s, which is that equal comparison between any value and `NULL` is always false.

If you `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF` then `@tmp = NULL` returns true.  However, I'd recommend against this approach